# Angular/material autocomplete: options do not render

Tags: autocomplete, material-design, angular-material, angular5

Angular version: 5.0.0
angular/material version: 5.2.4

I've got this form:

```
<form #updateForm="ngForm">
 <mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="studentFormControl [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let student of students" [value]="student">
    {{student}}
   </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And I've got this component:

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { MatInputModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  this.studentFormControl = new FormControl();
  this.students = ['hi', 'hello'];
...
}
```

Although the form shows up, the autocomplete box remains dimensionless without options rendered within:
[screenshot of input/autocomplete box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0acd.png)

It should be noted as well that the form is nested within an ngbModal. Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Your code is working fine.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but nothing shows up. The autocomplete element only has a comment <!---> as its inner content.

Comment: You know what, it is rendering. I think it is something that can be fixed with css.

Comment: Yes adjusting the index on the cdk-overlay-container solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm no expert here, but from what I understand, the autocomplete function requires an observable of sorts, at least if you want to be able to filter results as you type, to be selected. Since you are using an array you need to first turn it into an observable. As your array is loaded immediately you would need to use RXJS's subjects and more specifically the BehaviorSubject. 
Once it becomes an observable you can then call it using the asyncpipe on your form. 
This is not to say you couldn't have done it with an array and not used the asyncPipe, however that array would have to be loaded in OnInit. 
See the example for both

```js
import { Observable, from, Subscription, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  studentFormControl = new FormControl();
  studentFormControl1 = new FormControl();
  array = ['test','one','two'];
  array1=[];
  arrayObs: Observable<any>;
  arrayBehObs = new BehaviorSubject(this.array);
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    this.array1.push('test','one','two');
    this.arrayObs = this.returnAsObs();

  }
  private returnAsObs() {
    return this.arrayBehObs.asObservable();
  }

}
```

```html
<form #updateForm="ngForm">
        <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="studentFormControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let student of arrayObs|async" [value]="student">
                {{student}}
               </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>

            <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="studentFormControl1" [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let student of array1" [value]="student">
                    {{student}}
                   </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>



</form>
```